# Find $\delta$ for $Q(x)$ in terms of $\epsilon$

Tags: functions, epsilon-delta

This is a homework question.

[image]

I got all the way to 
$$|6x+47||x-8|<\epsilon$$
So I can isolate for $|x-8|$.

What do I do then?

Answer (score 1):

If you factor again $(x-8)$ out of $(6x+47)$ you get 
$$Q(x)-Q(8)=6(x-8)^2+95(x-8)$$

So $\left|Q(x)-Q(8)\right|\le 6|x-8|^2+95|x-8|<6\delta^2+95\delta=\delta(6\delta+95)$

Now if $\delta<\min\left(1,\dfrac{\varepsilon}{101}\right)$

Then $\left|Q(x)-Q(8)\right|<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{101}(6\times 1+95)=\varepsilon$

*I don't know why the proposed answer is $\dfrac{\varepsilon}{103}$ but since it is trivially smaller than $\dfrac{\varepsilon}{101}$, then it would fit also.*

Answer (score 0):

From $|6x+ 47||x- 8|< \epsilon$ you can immediately get $|x- 8|< \frac{\epsilon}{|6x+ 47|}$.

Now, you want to be able to find $\delta$ such that $|x- 8|< \delta$ leads to that.  That means you want $\delta$ less that $\frac{\epsilon}{|6x+ 47|}$ so we want a lower bound.  That fraction will be smallest when it denominator is largest.  So how do we put an  upper bound on |6x+ 47|?  If we first agree to look only at |x- 8|< 1 or -1< x- 8< 1, then -6< 6x< 6 and 41< 6x+ 47< 53.  That is, as long as we know |x- 8|< 1 we can be sure that |5x+ 47|< 53.  In that case, we know that $\frac{\epsilon}{|6x+ 47|}< \frac{\epsilon}{53}$.

(NOT 103. Are you sure you have copied that correctly?)

Comment: Yeah, I just screenshotted it. That's why I found it to be weird when I found a different answer. Thanks.

Comment: You have a minot mistake. When $-1<x-8<1$ then $-6<6x-48<6$ or $42<6x<54$ and $89<6x+47<101$.